# Configure a castle windsor TypedFactory with custom selector via xml?

Tags: castle-windsor, typed-factory-facility

I have the following configuration:

```
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>()
         .Register(Component.For<IMyFactory>()
                            .AsFactory(c => c.SelectedWith(new MyFactoryComponentSelector())));
```

The problem is that I need to configure it with xml. Is there an equivalent xml configuration?

Comment: Why do you need this via xml? Concretely what part of this registration (what type) do you need to configure via XML?

Comment: What I intended to do was to register the typed factory facility in the xml and then my factory, but i am not sure about how to indicate the component selector to my factory

Comment: so you need to make just `MyFactoryComponentSelector` configurable for this registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't. Why do that via xml? Why expose implementation details of your application to the outside world?

Comment: Actually the reason is that xml configuration is the prefered approach where I work. I haven´t convinced yet my coworkers to use the fluent API.

Comment: out of curiosity - why would you prefer this approach? It offers no benefits whatsoever over fluent API.

Comment: You are right, I can't think of a good reason for registering components via xml. I guess it's just the way they have always do it in here .Time to move to the fluent API. Thanks